# Prove $4\sin(40^{\circ})-\sqrt{3}=\cot(50^{\circ})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-writing, contest-math

Prove

> $$4\sin(40^{\circ})-\sqrt{3}=\cot(50^{\circ})$$

I started like this:

Let $\:$ $\tan(20^{\circ})=x$

$$4\sin(40^{\circ})-\sqrt{3}=\frac{8\tan(20^{\circ})}{1+\tan^2(20^{\circ})}-\left(\frac{3\tan(20^{\circ})-\tan^3(20^{\circ})}{1-3\tan^2(20^{\circ})}\right)=\frac{8x}{1+x^2}-\frac{3x-x^3}{1-3x^2}$$

Any way to continue from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4\sin40^{\circ}-\sqrt3=\frac{4\sin40^{\circ}\sin50^{\circ}-2\sin60^{\circ}\sin50^{\circ}}{\sin50^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{2\cos10^{\circ}-2\cos90^{\circ}-\cos10^{\circ}+\cos110^{\circ}}{\sin50^{\circ}}=$$
$$=\frac{\cos10^{\circ}+\cos110^{\circ}}{\sin50^{\circ}}=\frac{2\cos60^{\circ}\cos50^{\circ}}{\sin50^{\circ}}=\cot50^{\circ}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Note $\cot50^{\circ}=\frac{\sin40^{\circ}}{\cos40^{\circ}}$,

$$\begin{align}
& 4\sin40^{\circ}-\sqrt{3}-\cot50^{\circ}\\
& = \frac2{\cos40^{\circ}}\left(2\sin40^{\circ}\cos40^{\circ} -\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos40^{\circ}- \frac12\sin40^{\circ}\right) \\
& =  \frac2{\cos40^{\circ}}(\sin80^{\circ}-\cos(40^{\circ}-30^{\circ}))=0
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have $$\cot 50+\sqrt{3}=\frac{1}{\cos 40}(\sin 40+\sqrt{3}\cos 40)\\
=\frac{2}{\cos 40}(\frac12\sin 40+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos 40)\\=
\frac{2}{\cos 40}\cos10\\=\frac{2\sin80}{\cos 40}\\ =\frac{4\sin40\cos40}{\cos 40}\\=4\sin40$$